# How to implement user login with Google, Facebook or Twitter in Android app?

Tags: android, user-accounts

I am trying to implement user login via social networks to my app. User should login with their google, facebook or twiter account to the app and create content that will later be sent/or synced to the app rest service.

What is the best way to do this?

I was successful with adding google and facebook sign in button and getting auth tokens from them but then i started reading on some [tutorials](http://udinic.wordpress.com/2013/04/24/write-your-own-android-authenticator/) that include account manager which is needed to implement sync adapter for data that needs to be synced with server, but as i understood i need to create my own login and add new user implementation for this to work?

Can i use social login with sync adapter, or do i need to implement my own account management?

Please point me in the right direction.

Comment: https://androidbeasts.wordpress.com

Answer (score 1):

I personally avoid tutorials that "help" you to build a customized social API's interface, first because they could rely on old API version (take Facebook for example, their graph API authentication system has changed a lot through years), second because they could propose a solution that is not what you are really looking for.

Instead, why don't you simply follow the official tutorials from Facebook SDK page (https://developers.facebook.com/docs/android/scrumptious/), Google and so on?